# NSXMLParser: How to return the parseError if .parse() returns false?

Tags: swift, nsxmlparser

In Swift, I have been experimenting with `NSXMLParser`. In general I am confident with the concepts and the implementation.

Therefore I have, for example, a function `myFunc()` which will include a call to the `.parse()` method.

In the event that the `.parse()` method returns `false` how can I use the delegate function `parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError)` to return the `parseError` directly to `myFunc()`? How can I access the error?

I know that I could print the error. And I can see that I could assign its value to a variable with class level scope. But I am guessing there is a better was of getting it.

```
func myFunc() {
    // ...
    myXmlParser!.delegate = self
    if myXmlParser!.parse() != true {
       // ...
    }
}
```

And I implement the delegate functions

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    // ...
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    // ...
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    // ...
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    // I know that I could print(parseError) or assign its value to a variable wth class level scope
}
```

How can I return `parseError` or otherwise access it from `myFunc()` without passing its value to a variable with wider scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `parse()` method of `NSXMLParser` returns `false` then you
can use its

```
var parserError: NSError? { get } // can be called after a parse is over to determine parser state.
```

property to get information about the problem. The

```
var lineNumber: Int { get }
var columnNumber: Int { get }
```

properties give more information about the location of the error.
Example:

```
if !myXmlParser.parse() {
    let error = myXmlParser.parserError
    let line = myXmlParser.lineNumber
    let col = myXmlParser.columnNumber
    println("XML parsing failed at \(line):\(col): \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful answer.